# What is the ranking order for the second stage of elimination in Divergent?

Tags: divergent

What is the ranking order for the second stage of elimination in *Divergent*?  I don't have the book, so I can't check.

I've looked online, but can't find an exact order. I know it is Tris, then Peter, then either Will or Christina, and Al in last. Obviously I just need Will and Christina's order, but it would be great if I had the final rankings as well...

Answer (score 3):

It's Christina and then Will.

**Stage one:**

1. Edward
2. Peter
3. Will
4. Christina
5. Molly
6. Tris
7. Drew
8. All
9. Myra

**Stage two:**

1. Tris
2. Peter
3. Christina (actually 7th)
4. Will (actually 9th)
5. Al (last which actually is 9th so there is an error from the author for either how many or the positions of Cristina and Will)

**Stage three:**

1. Tris
2. Uriah
3. Lynn
4. Marlene
5. Peter
6. Will
7. Christina

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been trying to recreate divergent in Minecraft, and I wanted the rankings on the walls of the dorms, now that I have the correct information, I can finally complete the dauntless compound! Thanks again!